# Wordpress: How to append element after last p tag and before plugin content

Tags: php, wordpress

My apologies for not knowing what to look up for this..

I'm using this [Facebook Comments plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/comments-from-facebook/) in my theme. It's appending the Facebook Comments Plugin to the end of posts. I'm wanting to add some elements after the post content and before the plugin content, but I can't figure it out.

I've tried adding the element into my `single.php` file like so:

```
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

    ?>
    <div class="new_content"></div>
    <?php

    endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>
```

..but this places the content after the plugin element.

I've also tried adding this element inside various parts of the `content.php` file, like so:

```
<div class="new_content"></div>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

I assumed this would place the element at the end of the post, but the plugin element still is the first thing immediately after the end of the content for the post.

Here is a screenshot showing where the plugin (`id="wpdevar..."`) gets rendered in the HTML:

[image]

I'm trying to place an element before that one, within the parent `<div class=entry-content">`.

**I'm guessing I will need to append this content from within `functions.php`? Or maybe apply some sort of filter? How would I go about doing this? Thanks.**

Comment: Can you inspect the html on your page to see where the plugin code is adding it's content? Editing content.php is a good idea if you can find the right spot.

Comment: Thanks - went ahead and added a screenshot of where the plugin renders and where I'm trying to place my new element.